# Algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am trying to calculate the complexity of the following algorithm

```
private static List<int> GetIndexes(string strippedText, string searchText)
    {
        List<int> count = new List<int>();
        int index = 0;
        while (strippedText.Length >= index && index != -1)
        {
            index = strippedText.IndexOf(searchText.Trim(), index,
                                         StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                count.Add(index);
                index++;
            }
            else continue;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

I know that the loop has a complexity of `O(n)` if count increments by 1 on each iteration but, the increments depends from the indexes found. on each iteration it could increment 1 or `strippedText.lenght()`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Still, the worst case is O(n).

Comment: Have a look at the Big O page on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: O(-) will be the worst scenario
and only in the average case will take in consideration others factors ???

Comment: From the Wikipedia page: "A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function;"

Answer (score 3):

It is still `O(n)` - this is because it grows asymptotically at the same rate as `O(n)`

Big O notation is used for the upper-bound of algorithmic growth - that is, it's a function that the algorithm is guaranteed to grow at the same rate as, or slower than.

In the average case your algorithm will grow at rate `O(n/m)` where `m` is some estimate of the how dense the indexes are in your strings (0 = no indexes, 1 = index at every character). Assuming that's roughly constant over `n` you can ignore the `m` and still say the algorithm is `O(n)`.

The fact that, in the real world, your algorithm will almost certainly be faster than `O(n)` doesn't stop it begina n `O(n)` function.

---

Take a look at [this page](http://www.progressive-coding.com/tutorial.php?id=1), particularly:

> The symbol O is used to describe an asymptotic upper bound for the magnitude of a function in terms of another, simpler function.
>   This means that for x > k, when x tends to infinity, the value f(x) will always be inferior to C *g(x) (with C a constant).

Comment: m is dependent on `searchText`, so it's not constant. Consider search text with many repetitions (like 'ababab').

Comment: Yes, but as long as it's not dependent on the *length* of `searchText` then my point stands

Comment: That is, if `m` is basically orthogonal to `n` then `O(n/m) = O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

O(n) where n is the length of the strippedText string.

Worst case, every character will be equal to the searchText and will result in n itterations, but even if that isn't the case (which I am assuming it won't be) your average case will be some factor, c, of n where c is greater than zero but less than 1, so the number of loops will be cn, but a constant factor of n will still be represented as O(n).

Comment: Could you explain me 
> your average case will be some factor, c, of n where c is greater than zero but less than 1, so the number of loops will be cn, but a constant factor of n will still be represented as O(n).

i do not understand it

thanks

Comment: Big O notation deals with growth rates and is used to guage how the runtime of the algorithm changes as the size of your data set changes.  By definition O-notation provides an asymptotic upper bounds to within a constant factor.  So O(cn) = O(n) regardless of whether c is 0.00001 or c is 100000000.  It still grows at the same rate with respect to n, thus when describing the runtime of an algorithm, constant factors are typically thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

I would still say that it is O(n) (or at least At worst O(n), unless your index can be made less than -1 say -10, which would reset it further)

But yes O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's O(strippedText.Length*searchText.Length) since index of makes a comparison between characters in searchText and strippedText.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the strings `IndexOf()` method is implemented. Basically you just search through the whole string with `IndexOf()` - how efficient that is depends on the efficiency of that method.

There are several [string search algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) of different complexities ranging from `O(m+n)` to `O(m*n)` (`m` and `n` being the length of the two strings).

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that it's `O(n/m)` where `strippedText.Length == n` and `m` is the length of a prefix of `searchText` that is a suffix of `searchText` (if no such prefix exist it's the length of `searchText`).

Examples:

searchText = 'ababab'   --> m == 2

searchText = 'aaaaaa'   --> m == 1

searchText = 'abcabc'   --> m == 3

searchText = 'abcdefg'  --> m == 7